# wpf Закрытие Popup при потере фокуса, клике в другом месте

Tags: wpf, popup

У меня есть ToogleButton при нажатии на него у меня открывается всплывающая панель Popup, при повторном нажатии Popup скрывается.
Я хочу добиться поведения для Popup как у ComboBox то есть если я кликну в любом случайном месте, чтобы панель
всплывающая панель закрывалась. Сейчас панель закрывается только при смене фокуса.
Код

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="toggleBtn" Content="Нажми меня" Width="100" Height="30">
            <ToggleButton.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <ContentPresenter Margin="5"/>
                                <Path x:Name="arrow" Margin="5 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="Gray"
                  Data="M0,0 L4,4 L8,0 Z"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <Popup x:Name="popup" Placement="Bottom" AllowsTransparency="true" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=toggleBtn}"
               IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=toggleBtn}">
                            <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Это всплывающая панель"/>
                                    <Button Content="Кнопка"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="arrow" Property="Data"
                    Value="M0,4 L4,0 L8,4 Z"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="false" TargetName="popup"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ToggleButton.Template>
        </ToggleButton>
```

Пробовал так, но без успешно

```
private void Popup_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    toggleBtn.IsChecked = false;
}
```

Comment: Нужно смотреть в сторону `Mouse.Capture(...` и `AddHandler(Mouse.PreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElementEvent, mouseClickHandler);` попутно разгребая проблемы от контролов внутри попапа, которые могут сбросить захват (если таковые есть, например, TextBox)

Comment: Попробуйте обернуть его, например, `Border`'ом, который будет на все окно и иметь прозрачный цвет (`Transparent`), на него вешайте событие клика, по которому и закрывайте окно. И да, не забывайте метку c#, просто WPF мало кто смотрит)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ```И да, не забывайте метку c#, просто WPF мало кто смотрит)``` Принял, спасибо

Comment: @vitidev  ``` попутно разгребая проблемы от контролов внутри попапа, которые могут сбросить захват (если таковые есть, например, TextBox)``` а мне надо чтобы панель закрывалась при клике в любом другом месте. И у нас View часть, проблема должна решаться без средств C# я на этом раньше много костылей сделал.  90% задач решается чистым Wpf

Answer (score 1):

Upd: удалил старый пример.
Новый пример кода который корректно работает с фокусом всплывающего окна, нет мерцаний и т.п при срабатывание разных тригеров.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
 <Grid>
            <!--Шапка панели-->
            <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleBtn" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Width="255" Height="55" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <ToggleButton.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                    <Border Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource Color4}" BorderThickness="0 0 1 1">
                                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="18 11.5 8 4.5" Width="38" Height="38">
                                                <Ellipse Width="38" Height="38">
                                                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue"></SolidColorBrush>
                                                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                                                </Ellipse>
                                                <Label Padding="0" Content="R" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" Foreground="{DynamicResource Color0}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                            <StackPanel  Grid.Column="1" Margin="0 13.5 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                                <Label FontSize="16" Padding="0" FontFamily="Gilroy" Margin="0 0 0 2" FontWeight="Medium" Foreground="{DynamicResource Color9}">User</Label>
                                                <Label FontSize="12" Padding="0" FontFamily="Gilroy" FontWeight="Medium" Foreground="{DynamicResource Color7}">30.06.2023 - 30.07.2023</Label>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                            <Viewbox Name="BtnTitlePanel" Grid.Column="2" Margin="32 0 0 0" Width="12" Height="6">
                                                <Path x:Name="Arrow" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Fill="{DynamicResource Color6}" StrokeThickness="1.2"  StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" 
                                  Data="M0.211911 1.13721C-0.0706375 0.877061 -0.0706368 0.455269 0.211912 0.195115C0.49446 -0.0650384 0.952562 -0.0650384 1.23511 0.195115L6 4.58234L10.7649 0.195116C11.0474 -0.0650381 11.5055 -0.0650384 11.7881 0.195115C12.0706 0.455269 12.0706 0.877061 11.7881 1.13721L6.86498 5.67011C6.38727 6.10996 5.61273 6.10996 5.13502 5.67011L0.211911 1.13721Z">
                                                    <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                        <RotateTransform></RotateTransform>
                                                    </Path.RenderTransform>
                                                </Path>
                                            </Viewbox>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=popup, Path=IsOpen}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
                                                          From="0"   To="180" Duration="0:0:0.35"></DoubleAnimation>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" From="180"   To="0" Duration="0:0:0.35"></DoubleAnimation>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ToggleButton.Style>
            </ToggleButton>

            <Popup x:Name="popup" StaysOpen="False" PopupAnimation="Fade" Placement="Bottom" 
               AllowsTransparency="true" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=toggleBtn,Mode=TwoWay}" 
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=toggleBtn}" VerticalOffset="5">
                <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Content="Это всплывающая панель"/>
                        <Button Content="Кнопка"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Неплохие варианты, но все же плохо работают с элементами что захватывают мышь. Например, если разместить 2 календаря, то в 1 варианте после выбора даты на одном календаре клик на другом просто закроет попап. Во 2 варианте не закроет, но нужно будет 2 клика снаружи контрола чтобы сработал `StaysOpen=False`.

Comment: @vitidev обновил код на более рабочую версию, где решены проблемы которые вы описали.

Comment: Ну я взял ваш второй вариант, а проблема с календарями - проблема самих календарей, там их (календари) немного фиксишь и все работает.  В общем то без правки календарей нормального решения нет. С нормальными же контролами все должно быть проще

Comment: @vitidev второй вариант был рабочий, но работал по типу панели, увы. В новом варианте работает как нужно, при потере фокуса popup закрывается. А про календари возможно есть с ними такая проблема. Думаю код из ответа подойдет чтобы починить их.